# [PHRASE DESCRIBING THIS PUZZLE]

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: FIRST STAGE OF PUZZLE]
[image: SECOND STAGE OF PUZZLE]

---

This puzzle is also available as a spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fDFfO6VyJyDKgSrINlwfNZkNqLdTllekrF4bO2M8BMo).

Transcription of some of the text:

```
FIRST STAGE OF PUZZLE
α   BOGGLE
β   VIZIER
γ   ANGERS
δ   TENDON

α   LOSE
β   POSTSCRIPTS
γ   PURSUE
δ   MISGIVINGS

α   PANDA
β   LIME
γ   VANDALIZE
δ   JAPANIMATION

α   SPA
β   WALES
γ   PROTEIN
δ   ANGLICAN

SECOND STAGE OF PUZZLE
FIFTY SQUARED MINUS FORTY-ONE (1, 2, 3, 4)
DOT AND CROSS YOURS (3, 1, 2, 4)
FIRST FIVE LETTERS' BITS (3, 4, 1, 2)
LEMME GET THIS STRAIGHT (4, 2, 3, ????, 1)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This puzzle requires some...

> ...**FOUR-WORD THINKING**! (A pun on 'forward-thinking'...)

For the first stage of the puzzle, each of the four columns of words (alpha through delta) needs to be matched to a different quadrant of the diagram before these four sub-puzzles can be solved.

**FIRST STAGE OF PUZZLE**

**Sub-puzzle 1 (North-West corner):**

[image: Sub-puzzle 1]

> α LOSE, β POSTSCRIPTS, γ PURSUE, δ MISGIVINGS
>
>  Each of these words has a synonym which is a compound word or phrase of two 'halves' (albeit of differing lengths). These halves can be positioned in the mini-grid, one to a square, with their lengths matching the enumeration shown. Then reading across the rows and columns gives us these synonyms:
>
>  α LOSE = COME SECOND
>  β POSTSCRIPTS = AFTERTHOUGHTS
>  γ PURSUE = COME AFTER
>  δ MISGIVINGS = SECOND THOUGHTS
>
>  The green boxes highlight our answer: **AFTERTHOUGHTS**

**Sub-puzzle 2 (North-East corner):**

[image: Sub-puzzle 2]

> α PANDA, β LIME, γ VANDALIZE, δ JAPANIMATION
>
>  We need to solve the relationship αβ : γ :: δ : ___. In other words, by working out how to get γ (VANDALIZE) from α (PANDA) and β (LIME), we can then derive the answer by applying the same transformation to δ.
>
>  It's a short step to see that [V]ANDALI[Z]E is derived by concatenating and changing P to V and M to Z in [P]ANDA and LI[M]E. What word can we make by changing these letters in 'JAPANIMATION'? That would be **[JAVANIZATION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanisation)**.

**Sub-puzzle 3 (South-West corner):**

[image: Sub-puzzle 3]

> α SPA, β WALES, γ PROTEIN, δ ANGLICAN
>
>  This sub-puzzle was my break-in to the whole puzzle. The number 189819 is very famous for a particular reason - it is the length in characters of the longest word in English: the full name of the *protein* also known as [titin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titin). A little thought made me realise that each of the words in this section clues *a famously very long word*:
>
>  SPA = Aequeosalinocalcalinoceraceoaluminosocupreovitriolic (describing the *spa* waters at Bath, England) [3,4];
>  WALES = Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch (a place in *Wales*) [3,7,4];
>  PROTEIN = Methionylthreonylthreonylglutaminylalanyl…isoleucine (the aforementioned *protein*) [3,189819];
>  ANGLICAN = Antidisestablishmentarianism (opposition to the disestablishment of the *Anglican* Church) [7,3].
>
>  If we interpret the numbers in square brackets as identifying letters at these numbered positions, we retrieve the letters QU, AIN, TE and ST, giving us the word **QUAINTEST**.

**Sub-puzzle 4 (South-East corner):**

[image: Sub-puzzle 4]

> α BOGGLE, β VIZIER, γ ANGERS, δ TENDON
>
>  Here we are looking for an 11-letter word that could be found via the rules of [Boggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) (moving from one adjacent letter to another to trace out a word), after assembling the other three words into a 3x6 rectangular grid:
>
> ```
> VIZIER
> ANGERS
> TENDON
> ```

> Beginning in the bottom-left corner, we can find the word **TENDERIZING**.

**SECOND STAGE OF PUZZLE**

For this stage, we must number our answer words as per the sub-puzzle number in my description above:

> 1 = AFTERTHOUGHTS
>  2 = JAVANIZATION
>  3 = QUAINTEST
>  4 = TENDERIZING

FIFTY SQUARED MINUS FORTY-ONE (1, 2, 3, 4)

> The calculation results in the number 2459. If we position our words in the grid provided, repeatedly laying copies of the words side by side, ad infinitum, we get a grid that looks something like this:
>
>  [image: Grid with words repeating ad infinitum]
>
>  If we read off the letters (downwards) that would be in the 2459th column, we would be able to spell the word **FOUR** (the 2nd letter of A**F**TERTHOUGHTS, the 11th of JAVANIZATI**O**N, the 2nd of Q**U**AINTEST, and the 6th of TENDE**R**IZING).

DOT AND CROSS YOURS (3, 1, 2, 4)

> This is a reference to a well-known phrase about "dotting the i's and crossing the t's". If we extract all of the I's and T's from each word and replace each I with a dot and each T with a dash, we can generate some [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) letters (a method hinted at by 'dot', of course):
>
>  QUA[.]N[-]ES[-], AF[-]ER[-]HOUGH[-]S, JAVAN[.]ZA[-][.]ON, [-]ENDER[.]Z[.]NG
>
>  i.e. .-- / --- / .-. / -..
>
>  This spells out the word **WORD** in Morse code.

FIRST FIVE LETTERS' BITS (3, 4, 1, 2)

(Thanks to @fljx for solving this part in comments)

> Order the words as required and look at the 5 symbols given: '(', '—', '/', '\', and ')'. Now consider which of the first 5 letters in each word contain a segment ('bit') shaped (approximately) like each of these:
>
>  [image: First five letters bits]
>
>  If we then treat the *presence* of one of these segments as a '1' and its absence as a '0' we can produce four 5-digit binary numbers (containing '[bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)' of another kind!): 20, 8, 9 and 14. Using A1Z26, these numbers convert to letters to spell the word **THIN**.

LEMME GET THIS STRAIGHT (4, 2, 3, ????, 1)

[image: Lemme get this straight]

> The rectangles in this image strongly resemble *playing cards*. If we arrange the words in the given order - **TEN**DERIZING, **J**AVANIZATION, **Q**UAINTEST, ????, **A**FTERTHOUGHTS - we can see a pattern: each begins with a playing card in the sequential run of 10, Jack, Queen, [King], Ace (known as a 'straight' in poker). The missing card is our answer here: **KING**.

**PUTTING THIS ALL TOGETHER:**

> Finally, these four words can now be concatenated to make the relevant phrase '**FOUR-WORD THINKING**' (a play on words for 'forward thinking') - especially relevant since each starting set of words had four entries, and every phrase used in this puzzle, from 'FIRST/SECOND STAGE OF PUZZLE' right through to the four second-stage clues comprises precisely four words!

Comment: I think I have an explanation for the FIRST FIVE LETTERS' puzzle, but if I'm correct, your word 2 is slightly wrong.

Comment: To save a thousand words: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jADMK.png

Comment: @fljx Ah, that works! Because the rule for my sub-puzzle 2 can be tweaked to use specific letter-pair substitutions rather than just one random one per word. Great thinking! I shall update for completeness, thanks :)

Comment: GOOD WORK WELL DONE :)

Comment: @noneuclideanisms THANKS FOR GREAT PUZZLE!